# How do you train a model on a dataset that's unlabeled but we know the percentage of every class?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, image-processing, semi-supervised-learning

Say we have a data set that's pictures of apples and oranges, but we don't know which is which. However the data is organized in such a way, that for some groups of images we know how many of them are apples and how many are oranges. For example the dataset could consist of 1000 groups of images, each group contains 100 images and a label that's basically the percentage of the images in this group that are apples but not which ones are they.

Is it possible to train a model to classify this data? If so what's the technique called? How error tolerant is it (if the group labels are only an estimate and not precise)? Is there any recommended literature on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes called *learning from label proportions* in machine learning, falling into the realm of *weakly supervised classification*.

A machine learning paper that establishes one variant of the problem, along with some algorithms and some theoretical guarantees, is

> Quadrianto, Smola, Caetano, and Le. [*Estimating Labels from Label Proportions*](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v10/quadrianto09a.html). JMLR 2009.

There's been a decent amount of work on it since; check out papers citing that one.

A closely related problem, with a long history in statistics and political science, is *ecological inference*. This sometimes refers to inferring about subgroups, rather than individuals: given labels on how the total population of counties voted, how did different demographic groups vote? But it's also sometimes used to refer to individuals.